# How to transfer row data to specific cells in a variable sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

Ok, this might take a bit to explain. I have a single MS Excel setting log sheet for a machine in our plant that contains setting specs for over 100 different part numbers built on that machine (each row is a different part number). We're switching to a new format that will have a separate sheet for each part number, with each sheet following a certain format (I set up a template beforehand and copied it for each part number). The first column of the old log sheet contains all of the part numbers, and the sheet names correspond to these part numbers.

So I'm trying to set up a program that will repeat for each part number (each sheet), and will find that number in the first column of the old log sheet. Then it will pull the value from the cell in, let's say, column B of that row, and will place that value in a specific cell in the sheet for that part number. Now, this will need to pull data from several cells for each part number, but if I can get it to work for one, I can go from there.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
Sub EditSettings()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer

lastrow = Sheets("M200 46mm Setting Log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 5 To Worksheets.Count

    For j = 4 To lastrow

            If Sheets("M200 46mm Setting Log").Cells(j, "A").Value = "" Then

            ElseIf Sheets("M200 46mm Setting Log").Cells(j, "A").Value = Sheets(i).Name Then

                Sheets("M200 46mm Setting Log").Range(j, "B").Copy _
                Destination:=Sheets(i).Range("D11")

            End If

    Next

Next

End Sub
```

When I run this however, it gives me an error saying "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: You need to clarify the `rows.count` in finding the last row to `...Sheets("M200 46mm Setting Log").Rows.Count...`. Just to be safe

Comment: Yeah, it's always the small nuances like this that get me. I'll definitely remember to do this in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier than you might imagine. You don't need to loop through each of the worksheets because you can assign the target worksheet by its name: `Set ws = WorkSheets([name as a string])`. So you really only need to loop through the rows and pick up each sheet name.

I'd also recommend creating an address map of each old sheet cell and its new sheet cell address. In your example, column "B" goes to "D11", so create a collection of all of these and simply loop through them for the copying. There are quicker ways of doing it but with only 100 or so different parts it's not worth worrying about.

The code below shows you how to do both. From your question you mention that you have created templates for each new sheet. Presumably, then, the format is correctly set, so you've no need to do a copy/paste, just write each cell value to the new cell.

By the way, the most obvious error in your code (and probably the reason for your error) is that this line: `Sheets("M200 46mm Setting Log").Range(j, "B").Copy ...` should be `Sheets("M200 46mm Setting Log").Cells(j, "B").Copy ...`

```
Sub RunMe()
    Dim wsLog As Worksheet
    Dim wsPart As Worksheet
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim addressMap As Collection
    Dim map As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim r As Long

    Set addressMap = New Collection
    ' Map the transfer cell addresses
    addressMap.Add SetRangeMap("B", "D11")
    ' 1st item is old log sheet column, 2nd is address of new sheet
    ' ...
    ' ... repeat for all the address maps
    ' ...

    'Loop through the rows in the source sheet
    Set wsLog = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("M200 46mm Setting Log")
    lastRow = wsLog.Cells(wsLog.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 4 To lastRow
        ' Acquire the sheet name from the part number cell
        sheetName = CStr(wsLog.Cells(r, "A").Value2)
        ' Try to assign the parts number worksheet
        Set wsPart = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wsPart = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' If assigment worked then transfer data
        If Not wsPart Is Nothing Then
            For Each map In addressMap
                wsPart.Range(map(1)).Value = wsLog.Cells(r, map(0)).Value2
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Function SetRangeMap(sourceCol As String, partAddress As String) As Variant
    Dim map(1) As String
    map(0) = sourceCol
    map(1) = partAddress
    SetRangeMap = map
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly for all of the settings I had to carry over. And thank you for explaining how it worked as well. As I mentioned in my original post (before that sentence got removed), I'm pretty new to using macros and VBA, so I appreciate the opportunity to learn how it works rather than just copy, paste, and forget.